# Finding and replacing in a HTML file for WebView

Tags: java, android

I have a few key words I want to replace in a HTML file before it's shown to the user. I've done some searching and tried a few methods but I just can't get it to work.

Here's my current implementation:

```
    web_subscribe = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_subscribe);

    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("subscribe.html");
        int size = 0;
        size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String str = new String(buffer);
        str.replace("first_name",Globals.forename);
        str.replace("last_name", Globals.surname);
        str.replace("input_email", Globals.email);

        try {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("subscribe.html", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(str);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    web_subscribe.loadUrl("file:///data/data/uk.co.livingayurveda.vpkquestionaire/files/subscribe.html");
```

I'm not getting any errors, and the WebView displays correctly except without the replaced tags. So I'm guessing I'm just not loading the URL from the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably placed the html before replacing it's tag,so you can write a full page on the external SD storage then load the page from the external storage